# WYGWAM Field Blank

Tags: add-on, error, wygwam

I have added a WYGWAM field but when I go to the publish page, the field does not load. Just a blank space (see image: http://cl.ly/M5jJ).  When I inspect the page, I see the following error: coeditor.js - Type Issue 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'x.onLoad')

Anyone else run into this or have any idea how to resolve it? I have the following add-ons installed:

- CE Cache
- CE Image
- CE Img AWS
- Channel Files
- Channel Videos
- devot:ee Monitor
- Edit This
- EE Hive Hacksaw
- Hits
- Mountee
- Playa
- Tagger
- Template Variables
- TruncHTML
- Vz URL
- Wygwam

I also have an RTE field type (although not in use on the same publish page) which I'm trying to upgrade from. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Have you tried re-uploading the **/themes/third_party/wygwam/** directory?

Comment: Sorry, yes. That was my first thought. I also checked to make sure that the URL was the same (www vs non-www).

Comment: Are you getting any other JS errors on the page, before that one?

Comment: Just checked and this time I did get an error above that one. Error:plugin.js Semantic Issue Unexpected token '<'

Comment: If I were a betting man, I'd say you need to re-upload Channel Image's Wygwam plugin per their installation instructions.

Comment: If you were a betting man, you'd be a winner. That solved it. Thanks.

Comment: If Brad or Brad wanted to post that as the answer for future reference, that would be kind of you.

Comment: How do I mark a post as the answer? I can't find it here on the SE site.

Comment: Brad, just go ahead and copy and paste Brad Bell’s response into the “Your Answer” textarea below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-uploading Channel Image's Wygwam plugin per their installation instructions as recommended by Brad Bell solved this.

Comment: So mark the post as answered ;)

Comment: I guess this could be more complicated. Not sure how.